# Como colocar um botão que está no form e na mesma linha em uma coluna de tabela?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, tabela-html

Meu problema é o seguinte:
Estou usando bootstrap4 e gostaria de colocar os três botões na mesma linha.
como procedo?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<td class="col-4">
    <a href="/FAQCategory/{{ $FAQCategory->id }}" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Detalhar</a>
    <a href="/FAQCategory/{{ $FAQCategory->id }}/edit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Editar</a>
    <form action="FAQCategory/{{ $FAQCategory->id }}" method="post">
        @csrf
        @method('delete')
        <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Apagar</a>
    </form>
</td>
```

Comment: sendo que os outros 2 botoes sao apenas usados como links, porque nao mete a `<form>` a envolver os 3 botoes? e o botao "Apagar" devia set do tipo `<button type="submit"...>` para que execute a `action` da `<form>`

Comment: Obrigado @balexandre. Acabei usando o d-inline-block na classe do form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A forma mais simples seria aplicar `display: inline-block;` ao formulário. Uma vez que está a usar bootstrap, basta aplicar a classe `d-inline-block` no `form`.

Também concordo com a sugestão do @balexandre, mas ainda assim aplicaria a classe `form-inline` no formulário.

Comment: Obrigado dfvc. Usei sua solução. Ficou perfeito.